# True or False: If for the function $g(x)$ we have that $g(a+b)=g(a)+bg(b)$, entails $g'(x)=g(0)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need help with this exercise.

**True or False:**

If for the function $g(x)$ we have that $g(a+b)=g(a)+bg(b)$, entails $g'(x)=g(0)$.

I tried to look for a function $g(x)$ that satisfy the hypothesis $g(a+b)=g(a)+bg(b)$ to check if the conclusion $g'(x)=g(0)$ is true or not but I can't find it.

Any help  will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Let $a=x$ and $b=h,0$

Comment: How is the derivative  defined?

Comment: You need continuity of $g$. (Boundeness (locally) would imply continuity), but, as it stands, the claim is false.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x$ be a nonzero constant such that

- $g(x)$, $g(-x)$, and $g(0)$ are defined; and
- the cases of the functional relation involving just $g(x)$, $g(-x)$, and $g(0)$ all hold.

Then $$g(x)=g(-x)=g(0)=0\text{.}$$

It's a matter of elementary linear algebra—no regularity assumptions, case-splitting, or calculus, and no divisions except by $x$ and $2$. And since $x$ is arbitrary, a $g$ that satisfies the functional equation everywhere must vanish identically, so that $g'(x)=g(0)$ trivially.

---

For we have
$$\begin{align}
 g(0) &= g(x) - x g(-x) \\
 g(0) &= g(-x) + x g(x)\text{;}
\end{align}$$

adding $x$ times the second equation to the first gives

$$(1+x)g(0) = (1+x^2)g(x)\text{.}$$

We also have $g(x) = g(0) + x g(x)$; multiplying both sides by $(1+x)$ and rearranging gives
$$(1+x)g(0) = (1-x^2)g(x)\text{.}$$
Adding the two displayed equations gives $2 g(x)= 2(1+x)g(0)$; multiplied by $\tfrac{1}{2}$, we get $$\boxed{g(x)=(1+x)g(0)}\text{,}$$ and multiplying *that* equation by $1-x$ gives
$$(1-x)g(x)=(1-x^2)g(0)\text{.}$$
But we also have $(1-x)g(x) = g(0)$, and subtracting the former equation from the latter yields $x^2 g(0)=0$; since $x^{-1}$ exists, we have
$$\boxed{g(0)=0}\text{.}$$

Answer (score 1):

The only continuous solution is $g(x)=0$, and clearly for this particular $g$, $g'(x)=g(0)=0$ for all $x$.

Using the definition of derivative and the fact that $g$ is continuous at $0$,

$$g'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x)+hg(h)-g(x)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{hg(h)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} g(h)=g(0).$$

This implies that $g$ has a constant derivative, so $g$ must be a linear polynomial, i.e., $g(x)=mx+b$ for some slope $m$ and $y$-intercept $b$. In fact, the above says that the slope (derivative) and $y$-intercept must be the same, i.e., $m=b$. So, $g(x)=ax+a$ for $a=m=b$.

The equation $g(x+y)=g(x)+yg(y)$ then becomes $a(x+y)+a=ax+a+y(ay+a)$.

Expanding out, one then gets $ax+ay+a=ax+a+ay^2+ay$. So, $ay^2=0$ for all $y$, which means that $a=0$.

So, $g(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Given that $g(a+b)=g(a)+bg(b)$ true for all values of $a$ and $b$,

Let $g(0)=k$

by substituting $a=0$ and $b=x$,

$g(x)=g(0)+xg(x)$,hence

$(1-x)g(x)=g(0)$

$(1-x)g(x)=k$

$g(x)=k/(1-x)$ ......(1)

putting $a=x$ and $b=2$ in original equation,we get

$g(x+2)=g(x)+2g(2)$

also $g(x+2)=-k/(x+1)$ and $2g(2)=-2k$ ....(from (1))

hence,$-k/(x+1)=((k)/(1-x))-2k$

rearranging

$k((-1/(x+1))+1/(x-1))+2)=0$...(it must be true for all x except 1)

Hence k must be $0$,$k=0$

Hence $g'(x)=g(0)/(x-1)^2$(for all values of x except 1)

As derived $k=0$

hence $g(x)=0$,but one must also note that in order to make function
continuous,it must be defined that $g(1)=0$

Comment: Wher does "also it is given g'(x)=0 for all values of x" come from?

Comment: @anne bauval,I have edited to rectify The missing steps

Comment: Note that $k=0$ can be derived directly from $(1-x)g(x)=g(0)$ applied to $x=1.$ And then, $g(x)=0$ for every $x\ne1$ follows.

Comment: I purposely avoided using g(1) in order to decrease further doubts or downvotes stating that what if g(1) is not defined or function is not continuous at x=1!!

Answer (score 0):

I will assume $g$ is a real-valued function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ (or an open subset thereof).

Recall that $$g'(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}$$ (if the limit exists).

Using the given property of $g$, $$g(x+h) = g(x) + hg(h),$$ so now $$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{hg(h)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0} g(h),$$

which by definition is equal to $g(0)$ exactly when $g$ is continuous at 0.

Let $t \in \mathbb{R} \backslash{\{1\}}$ be arbitrary and write $$g(t+0) = g(t) + 0g(0).$$ On the other hand, $$g(t+0) = g(0+t) = g(0) + tg(t).$$

Rearranging yields $$g(t) = \frac{g(0)}{1-t}, t \neq 1.$$

The quotient of two continuous functions is continuous (where the denominator is non-zero). Well, the function $t \mapsto 1-t$ is continuous and non-zero away from $t \neq 1$, so $g$ is continuous away from 1 and particularly at 0.

As a result, the conclusion holds. *True.*

Comment: The equation $g(a+b)=g(a)+bg(b)$ is not actually satisfied for $g(t)=\frac{k}{1-t}$ for an arbitrary value $k$ of $g(0)$.

Comment: Okay; the hypothesis may not allow $g(0)$ to be arbitrary.

Comment: In fact, $g(t)=\frac{k}{1-t}$ satisfies the equation only for $k=0$.

Comment: That is not surprising given the fragility of the condition on $g$, but the implications in the argument should not be assumed to be bidirectional anyway.